# What is the dataWithContentsOfURL equivalent in android?

Tags: ios

Hi I am trying to get video data from a url. My project is written in swift. There they use `dataWithContentsOfURL`. Someone know what is the equivalent for android

```
data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoUrl options:0 error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite generic, but if you want to play video from a public URL, you could do something like this (extracted from Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html):

```
String url = "http://........"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
mediaPlayer.start();
```

If you need something more advanced, you should try ExoPlayer: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

But if you just want to download video data to manipulate somehow, you could use plain HttpURLConnection (NOT on Main Thread):

```
URL url = new URL("http://.....");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.connect();
OutputStream output = null; // whatever is your destination (file, memory, network)
InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
byte data[] = new byte[4096];
int count;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}
input.close();
output.close();
conn.disconnect();
```